# how to set language to searching in API Query?

Tags: oauth, instagram

I need to filter the result for turkish lang in instagram api. Such as `https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/mytag/media/recent?client_id=ClientID&lang=tr`. 
Is it possible ?

Comment: Please also give us a little more information? Why do you feel its not possible? Have you tried it? What result are you getting?

Comment: yes of course, I have tried it but there is no just turkish result.

Comment: as far as i can tell this isn't possible. Its possible to narrow by area but not by language